# Adding Text in a nested form with ActiveAdmin

Tags: activeadmin, formtastic

When adding nested attributes to an ActiveAdmin form, how can I add a label of a non editable attribute?

```
f.inputs do
  f.has_many :taggings do |t|
    t.div :name  # t.div is not a method.
    t.input :tag
  end
end
```

Is there a way to insert a text item in the ol of items?

Answer (score 0):

This discussion has a number of solutions

https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/issues/795

```
f.template.concat "<h1>Your Ad Here</h1>".html_safe
```